# Property 'x' does not exist on type 'true | Point'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have `ctx` variable of type `boolean | Point` where `Point` is:

```
type Point = {
    x: number
    y: number
}
```

I have a simple React component:

```
const App = () => {
  const [ctx, toggleCtx] = React.useState<boolean | Point>(false)

  return (
    <>
      <button
        className="w-4 h-4 mb-2 mr-2 rounded shadow"
        onContextMenu={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
          e.preventDefault()
          if (e.type === 'contextmenu') {
            toggleCtx({
              x: e.pageX,
              y: e.pageY,
            })
          }
        }}
      />
      {ctx && (
        <button
          style={{
            top: ctx.x,
            left: ctx.y,
          }}
          onClick={() => {
            toggleCtx(false)
          }}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Now notice the `Delete` button. I want to call it only when `x` & `y` is set & not when `ctx` contains boolean values.

It currently gives an error on `ctx.x` & `ctx.y` in `Delete` button:

> Property 'x' does not exist on type 'true | Point'. Property 'x' does not exist on type 'true'.ts(2339) Property 'y' does not exist on type 'true | Point'. Property 'y' does not exist on type 'true'.ts(2339)

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ctx &&` just checks that `ctx` is *truthy*. Both `true` (the other boolean value) and `Point` instances are truthy.

There are at least three ways to solve this. The first of them is the standard way I'd recommend using.

### Use `null`, not `boolean`

Instead of `const [ctx, toggleCtx] = React.useState<boolean | Point>(false)`, use:

```
const [ctx, toggleCtx] = React.useState<null | Point>(null)
```

and change `toggleCtx(false)` to `toggleCtx(null)`.

### Be more specific in your check

If you want to keep `boolean`, be more specific in your check: `typeof ctx === "object"`

```
{typeof ctx === "object" && (
  <button
    style={{
      top: ctx.x,
      left: ctx.y,
    }}
    onClick={() => {
      toggleCtx(false)
    }}
  >
    Delete
  </button>
)}
```

### Use `false` instead of `boolean`

The third option is to use `false` instead of `boolean`:

```
const [ctx, toggleCtx] = React.useState<false | Point>(false)
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

But this is pretty much the same as the `null` option, which is the more common way of doing it.

---

But again, using `null` is the standard way people handle this.

Comment: oh lord i did try `typeof ctx === Point` before but it gave error as `Point` is not a type in JS but didn't try `object`. thank you :)

Comment: @deadcoder0904 - Glad that helped! There's a better overall solution, though; I've updated the answer to show it. :-)

Comment: looks great. i used `null` which is better imo too as I never set it to `true` anyways :)